# Integer programming with Matlab

Tags: optimization, matlab, constrained-optimization

I'd like to know how to solve in MATLAB the following integer optimization problem :

$\underset{B,D}{\arg\min} \Vert{Y-XDB}\Vert_{2}$

where $X,Y$ are given matrices.

The constraint is the following : the matrix $D$ must be a diagonal matrix and its elements must be 0 or 1.

Comment: Matrix $B$ does not have any restrictions? And what are the sizes of all matrices?

Comment: Matrix $B$ has no particular restriction, it is the regression operator to be determined. The size o the matrixe are the following: X and  Y are $N \times n$, D is $ n \times n$ and $\beta$ $ n \times p$.

Comment: If $X$ is invertible wouldn't $D=I$ and $B=X^{-1}Y$ be the solution? Or are you also looking for solutions when $X$ is not invertible?

Comment: Indeed, but the purpose is also to find the matrix D that minimizes this norm. Besides, D must be diagonal with 0 or 1 as diagonal elements. I know this problem is related to Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The identify matrix $I$ only has ones on its diagonal, so satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Indeed, but i should precise that i want to obtain the most sparse matrix D while returning the minimal residual norm error. This problem can be seen as a optimization problem to select the smallest set of variables contained in X with the best approximation error.

Comment: Then your objective function should include that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem can be solved using heuristic methods, like particle swarm optimization or genetic algorithms.

Comment: care to be more specific?